# Error when adding VideosLibrary capability in app's manifest file

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464936.aspx#VideosLibrary), capabilities must be declared when an application requires programmatic access to certain user resources such as the Videos Library.

[This page of the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464936.aspx#VideosLibrary) also states: `All Windows Phone capabilities are not available for apps being developed specifically for Windows 10 Insider Preview`.

I am building a Universal Windows Application for Windows 10 and I would like to register the capability to access the videos library in my package.appmanifest file. However, when I do so I receive an error:

`The 'Name' attribute is invalid - The value 'videosLibrary' is invalid according to its datatype 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/types:ST_Capability_Foundation'`

Unfortunately, if I follow the link in the error message the page simply displays:

`The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.`

Here is a screenshot of the code (note that the other capabilites work correctly):

[image]

Is it currently not possible to register capabilites for applications being developed for Windows 10 or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn996898.aspx).

Basically you need to use

`<uap:Capability Name="VideosLibrary" />`

instead of

`<Capability Name="VideosLibrary" />`.